# Drupal: adding custom content type into a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm very new to drupal (started yesterday), I have created a content type called question and have added some questions. I want to create a question view page. When I go to add view -> node -> next. I select a page view but here is where I get confused. I'm not sure how/where to choose that it's questions I want to list.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the Filter by section to reduce the results. For example, Filter by: Node Type: (your node type) will reduce the results down to nodes of that type.